# upgrade Lotus notes to IBM Notes 8.0 or 8.5

Tags: lotus-notes

We are having Lotus notes 4.5 database. 
We want to upgrade it to IBM Notes 8.0 or 8.5.
Is it possible ?
if yes, can you give the link or reference.

Answer (score 4):

A 4.5 database should work **without any changes** on a 8.x server or client. Only in rare cases you need something to change. If that is the case then post the issue here on stackoverflow.

Make sure to [change ODS version of database](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/database-ods-version-should-be-upgraded-to-the-latest-) so it can use the improvements of 8.x IBM Notes version.

You might want to use new design possibilities to improve the user experience but that is just the next step.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "standalone" 4.5 Database: You need a server or a client to access the data in the database.

If your question is, whether you can update the Client / Server to 8.5 (better use the current version 9), then the answer is already given by Knut: All 4.5 database should (mostly) work on an 8.5 server or in a 8.5 client.

BUT: Updating a Client or Server from 4.5 to a current Version directly is not possible. You either need to take a lot of steps in between or completely reinstall the new Client / Server using existing databases (names.nsf, etc.).

As execution order of Notes Formula Language has significantly changed from 4 to 5 and the formula engine has been completely redone in Version 6 there might be some buttons that do not do in the new version what they where supposed to do in 4.5

So: the short answer is "yes", the long answer is: find someone to help you with this...